# I have generated an Run-time #3 exception in my c++ code

Tags: c++, exception

The exception is "Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'VfMin' is being used without being initialized".What can i do about it? Please i don't know how to handle exceptions if someone cared to explain them to me.

```
#include <fstream>
#define NMAX 50
#define INF 10000

using namespace std;

int n, x0;
double C[NMAX][NMAX];
int pre[NMAX], M[NMAX];
double d[NMAX];

void Init();
void Print();

int main()
{
//This is the algorithm itself
    int i, VfMin, j;
    double dMin;
//Initializing the values
    Init();
    for (j = 1; j < n; j++)
    {
        dMin = INF;
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            if (!M[i] && dMin > d[i])
            {
                dMin = d[i];
                VfMin = i;
            }
        }
        M[VfMin] = 1; //Generated exception
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            if (!M[i] && d[i] > dMin + C[VfMin][i])
            {
                pre[i] = VfMin;
                d[i] = dMin + C[VfMin][i];
            }
        }
    }
//Printing the results
    Print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre], presumably you aren't assigning a value to `VfMin` before you use it

Answer (score 0):

You set a value to `VfMin` variable inside an `if` block. If the `if` condition is never `true`, then your `VfMin` remains uninitialized. You can set`VfMin` to a default value. This can be an example (supposing that the rest of the algorithm is well written, this code should work):

```
int main()
{
    //This is the algorithm itself
    int i, VfMin, j;
    double dMin;
    //Initializing the values
    Init();
    for (j = 1; j < n; j++)
    {
        dMin = INF;
        VfMin = -1; // default value
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            if (!M[i] && dMin > d[i])
            {
                dMin = d[i];
                VfMin = i;
            }
        }

        if (VfMin != -1)
        {
            M[VfMin] = 1;

            for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            {
                if (!M[i] && d[i] > dMin + C[VfMin][i])
                {
                    pre[i] = VfMin;
                    d[i] = dMin + C[VfMin][i];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //Printing the results
    Print();
    return 0;
}
```

Also pay attention that in `C++` the first element of and array of `n` elements is at index `0` and the last element is at index `n-1`.